# Trying to divide main controller method to two separate methods

Tags: php, forms, symfony, methods, controller

I'm trying to divide the main method in my controller, to have two separate methods - one for returning generated form, and one for uploading file in this form. But I cannot grasp it with my mind how to do it...

Here is my currently working controller:

```
class UploaderController extends AbstractController
{
    private ConfigVendors $configVendors;

    public function __construct(ConfigVendors $configVendors)
    {
        $this->configVendors = $configVendors;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="upload_terms")
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function formRender(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
        $formUploader = new FormUploader();
        $form = $this->createForm(FormUploaderType::class, $formUploader);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $catalog = $request->request->get('form_uploader')['service'];

            $fileNameGenerator = new FileNameGenerator($request);
            $originalFileName = $fileNameGenerator->getOriginalFilename();
            $tmpPath = $fileNameGenerator->getFilePath();

            $upload = new Uploader($catalog.'/'.$originalFileName, file_get_contents($tmpPath));

            if (!$upload->gitlabUpload()) {
                $this->addFlash('danger', $translator->trans('uploadTermsError'));
            } else {
                $url = $this->configVendors->vendorUrl($catalog).'/'.$catalog.'/'.$originalFileName;
                $this->addFlash('success', $translator->trans('uploadTermsSuccess'));
                $this->addFlash('info', $url.'<br><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">Podgląd</a> <br><br> Plik będzie dostępny po kilku minutach, proszę o cierpliwość!');
            }

            return $this->redirectToRoute('upload_terms');
        }

        return $this->render('uploader/upload.html.twig', [
            'createForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here is my attempt to divide it...

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="upload_terms")
 */
public function getIndexAction()
{
    /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
    $formUploader = new FormUploader();
    $form = $this->createForm(FormUploaderType::class, $formUploader);

    return $this->render('uploader/upload.html.twig', [
        'createForm' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/", name="upload_terms")
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function formUpload(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
    $formUploader = new FormUploader();
    $form = $this->createForm(FormUploaderType::class, $formUploader);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $catalog = $request->request->get('form_uploader')['service'];

        $fileNameGenerator = new FileNameGenerator($request);
        $originalFileName = $fileNameGenerator->getOriginalFilename();
        $tmpPath = $fileNameGenerator->getFilePath();

        $upload = new Uploader($catalog.'/'.$originalFileName, file_get_contents($tmpPath));

        if (!$upload->gitlabUpload()) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', $translator->trans('uploadTermsError'));
        } else {
            $url = $this->configVendors->vendorUrl($catalog).'/'.$catalog.'/'.$originalFileName;
            $this->addFlash('success', $translator->trans('uploadTermsSuccess'));
            $this->addFlash('info', $url.'<br><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">Podgląd</a> <br><br> Plik będzie dostępny po kilku minutach, proszę o cierpliwość!');
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('upload_terms');
    }

}
```

Comment: And what's your question? It's not possible to do it this way, as you cannot trigger two actions on one request (at least not without writing more code). A better solution could be to use seperated services

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public function formUpload(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
        $formUploader = new FormUploader();
        $form = $this->createForm(FormUploaderType::class, $formUploader);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $catalog = $request->request->get('form_uploader')['service'];
            $fileNameGenerator = new FileNameGenerator($request);
            $originalFileName = $fileNameGenerator->getOriginalFilename();
            $tmpPath = $fileNameGenerator->getFilePath();
            $upload = new Uploader($catalog.'/'.$originalFileName, file_get_contents($tmpPath));
            $this->gitlabupload($upload, $translator, $catalog, $originalFileName);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('upload_terms');
        }

        return $this->render('uploader/upload.html.twig', [
            'createForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    private function gitlabupload($upload, $translator, $catalog, $originalFileName)
    {
        if (!$upload->gitlabUpload()) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', $translator->trans('uploadTermsError'));
        } else {
            $url = $this->configVendors->vendorUrl($catalog).'/'.$catalog.'/'.$originalFileName;
            $this->addFlash('success', $translator->trans('uploadTermsSuccess'));
            $this->addFlash('info', $url.'<br><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">Podgląd</a> <br><br> Plik będzie dostępny po kilku minutach, proszę o cierpliwość!');
        }
    }
```

Comment: and last question, how can I add the method("GET") in the annotations? Because right now it throws me an errors that this method is not allowed...

Comment: follow with the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html
@Route(... methods={"GET"})